# Something wrong in `Resolve`?

Tags: resolve

```
In[17]:= Resolve[ForAll[x, Sqrt[x] \[Element] Reals, x >= 0]]

Out[17]= False
```

I have tried to simplify an expression, but could not get the result I want. Then I tried  `Resolve`, but It seems that there were something wrong with it, like this

[image]